# How to set connection with database in the api Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to create the api on my linux PC. At this moment I have support for some basic requests which were done just for testing. My api works in cooperation with `uswgi+nginx+flask`. And now I'm trying to add connection to the database. For this purpose I had installed `MySQL` and created database. But I don't understand how to connect from the api to database. For example here is code of the script which can connect to the DB but it works separately of the api:

```
try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                                database='tired_db',
                                                user='test',
                                                password='pw')
            if connection.is_connected():
                mycursor = connection.cursor()

                mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")

                for x in mycursor:
                    print(x)
                return connection
        except Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
        finally:
            if connection.is_connected():
                mycursor.close()
                connection.close()
                print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

and it works correctly. I thought that maybe I can call this connection like some metaclass:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error


class DbProvider(type):
    @property
    def my_data(cls):
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                                database='tired_db',
                                                user='test',
                                                password='pw')
            if connection.is_connected():
                mycursor = connection.cursor()

                mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")

                for x in mycursor:
                    print(x)
                return connection
        except Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
        finally:
            if connection.is_connected():
                mycursor.close()
                connection.close()
                print("MySQL connection is closed")


class MyClass(metaclass=DbProvider):
     pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass.my_data
```

but I think that such stuff can be done with more efficient way. For example here is some request in the api:

```
@app.route("/api/login", methods = ['POST'])
def logIn():
    return "all is ok"
```

and the idea is that for example I have to connect during this request to the DB and check whether a user exists or not and if all is ok generate+save some token to the database. I don't understand whether it is important to keep connection alive during all api uptime or only during requests. And also is it important to close connection after an every request or we have to keep alive it forever. And also how to call connection from separate class, or I have to have all stuff in one file together with api calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a connection manager class that connects to the database, performs operations, and closes the connection.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self, host, database, user, password):
        self.host = host
        self.database = database
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=self.host,
                database=self.database,
                user=self.user,
                password=self.password
            )
            if self.connection.is_connected():
                self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
                return self.cursor
        except Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.connection.is_connected():
            self.cursor.close()
            self.connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

@app.route("/api/login", methods = ['POST'])
def logIn():
    with ConnectionManager('localhost', 'tired_db', 'test', 'pw') as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", ('test_user',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            # generate and save token
            return "all is ok"
        else:
            return "user not found"
```

Comment: and is it possible to move this manager to the separate file also? I mean how to import it correctly?

Comment: Create a file named connection_manager.py (for example). and put the ConnectionManager class inside it. in your Flask application, you can import the class by adding this line of code: from connection_manager import ConnectionManager

Comment: but when I move it to the separate file and add import I got the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`, I need to add some mysql imports to the file which will use connection_manager?

Comment: In the connection_manager.py file, you will need to import the following:



import mysql.connector from mysql.connector import Error 

And in the file that uses the ConnectionManager class, you will need to import the ConnectionManager class:



from connection_manager import ConnectionManager

Comment: in the `connection_manager` I have all required imports and the file which will use it also, but maybe I need for example reload uswgi or smth like that? because reload system service does not help